# Getting DataGrid Row by bound object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `List<T>` collection which is bound to a DataGrid. `T` is some class with some public properties, all have PropertyChangedEventHandler defined in order to update the grid properly, everything works just great. The only problem is that I don't know how to get reference to a row, to which my collection entry is bound.

For example:

```
List<T> collection = new List<T>();

// List has been filled with <T> objects
```

How can I determine to which DataGrid row (or cell), collection[23] object is bound to? How can I return reference to this row?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Can you show your code or how you tried to do?

Comment: Why do you need to know the Row of the bound object? You can use the [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator_methods.aspx), however quite often this is not needed if the problem is approached from a different angle.

Comment: Posting the whole code will be a mess since its quite long, and I don't really think it will help solving the problem. I need to know the row in order to change its background color, depending on the value of the Status property of the bound object. Status change occurs in a different thread, and I use the `Dispatcher.Thread` method in order to update the corresponding cell in DataGrid Status column. But in that method I actually update the Status property of the binded object, not dealing with Datagrid directly, thus, I don't know how to access the relevant cell/row directly.

Comment: I know that I can use Triggers in order to change the background color, but it seems to be too restrictive, I want more freedom here.

Comment: You can either use triggers as you mentioned, or (be careful with this) use relative binding.

Comment: Thank you all for helping, the problem was solved by Rachel :) I used the `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(binded_object)` method of my DataGrid instance and got the actual DataGridRow reference, that was exactly what I needed.

Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(binded_object)` method of my DataGrid instance as Rachel suggested and got the actual DataGridRow reference, that was exactly what I needed.